# How to modify calling object inside class method - C#

Tags: c#, class

This may have already been answered or not possible but I do not know exactly what this type of operation would be called.

I want to be able to change an instantiated object from a method inside that objects class. So for example:

```
public class Example
{
     private string SomeProperty {get;set;}

     public Example(string propValue)
     {
         SomeProperty = propValue;
     }

     public void Assign(string newPropertyValue)
     {
         this = new Example(newPropertyValue);
     }
}
```

Then to implement:

```
public Main()
{
     Example test = new Example("value");

     Example.Assign("newValue");
}
```

Or if there are any better ways to achieve this type of result that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: would a static instance work? what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: You cannot do this. An object's type is immutable. The `this` reference is read-only.

Comment: As `SomeProperty` has a setter, why not just do `test.SomeProperty = "newValue"`?

Comment: Is this an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/213688)?

Comment: What I am trying to do is use an explicit operator so I can have the functionality to do something like ClassObject = (Class)PropertyValue without having to do something like 

ClassObject = new Class(NewPropertyValue).

What I was trying to do was avoid the syntax of:
(Class)PropertyValue by having an assign function.

So using the syntax ClassObject.Assign(NewPropertyValue) would do the same thing as ClassObject = (Class)NewPropertyValue.

Comment: Well that doesn't really make sense since the only property you show is of type `string`, and your class is of type `Example`.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry to get a response out I didnt use the examples information.

ExampleObject = "newstring"

Comment: It _sounds_ like you want something like an [implicit operator overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit)...though I still don't think it's warranted based on what you've described.

Comment: @KennethK. that's exactly what I'm doing. I'm using an explicit operator though. What I was basically trying to achieve is instead of doing:

ExampleObject = (Example)"newString" which would call that explicit operator
I wanted to do something like ExampleObject.Assign("newstring")
So someting like public void Assign(string newStringVar){ this = newStringVar;}
But since this is read only that would not work. I was just unsure if there was a way to do something like this. Where a class method can perform that functionality on the instantiated object that called it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning `this` works only for value types (structs):

```
public struct Example
{
     public string SomeProperty {get;set;}

     public Example(string propValue) : this()
     {
         SomeProperty = propValue;
     }

     public void Assign(string newPropertyValue)
     {
         this = new Example(newPropertyValue);
     }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Example test = new Example("value");
    test.Assign("newValue");
    Console.WriteLine(test.SomeProperty); // prints "newValue"
}
```

However, this is really unclean and unconventional. Better to create a static method with `ref` argument (I have to mention this is quite a silly example considering simply setting the property would also work):

```
public static void Replace(ref Example example, string newPropertyValue)
{
    example = new Example(newPropertyValue);
}
```

Test:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Example test = new Example("value");
    Example.Replace(ref test, "newValue");
    Console.WriteLine(test.SomeProperty); // prints "newValue"
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would want if I wasnt trying to not pass the object to the method. But what I'm trying to do is have a method inside the class that can be called by an instantiation that will change that instantiation using an explicit operator that is also defined in the class. It's probably a terrible way to do something but I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Due to *this* being read only, the behavior I was after is not possible. I decided to instead make the assign function non static and include optional parameters to change the properties of the calling object.

Something like

```
public void Assing(string newProperty = "")
{
    if(newProperty != "")
    {
       SomeProperty = newProperty;
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone for your input!